# Need to extract data from a column, if a particular character exists, extracting the substring before the character

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I've got a column which I am trying to clean, the data is like this:

[image]

Wherever the pattern is of x-y year, I want to extract only the 'x' value and leave it in the string.
For any other value, I want to keep it as is.

Using str.extract('(.{,2}(-))') is returning a NaN value for all the other rows.

Comment: I'd suggest adding an example frame that someone can copy and run and providing an example of what result you want.  Currently the question is not very clear and an image isn't of much use unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The solution first compiles the regex then the compiled regex will be used on each row.
The lambda also relies on the walrus operator `:=`.
Assumes that your 2nd column is named `col2`.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("([\d]+)-[\d]+ year")
df["col2"] = df["col2"].map(lambda x: m[1] if (m:=pattern.match(x)) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), I believe.

Does this give you the desired output?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[1778, '3-5 year'], [961, np.nan], [2141, 'h 3+ year']], columns=['a','b'])

repl = lambda m: m.group(1)
df.b = df.b.str.replace(r'(\d+)-\d+\syear', repl, regex=True)
df
```

which takes the original `df`:

```
      a          b
0  1778   3-5 year
1   961        NaN
2  2141  h 3+ year
```

and gives the output:

```
      a          b
0  1778          3
1   961        NaN
2  2141  h 3+ year
```